# How to add rest API request time out in OAuth2RestTemplate in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, oauth2resttemplate

In my spring boot microservices, I am using OAuth2RestTemplate to make rest API call. Now, We have to add request time out in rest api call and for that I tried
**spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=20000 in application.properties** file but did not work.

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig {

   @Bean
   @LoadBalanced
   @Qualifier("oauth2BalancedRestTemplate")
   public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2BalancedRestTemplate(@Qualifier("oauth2RestTemplate") OAuth2RestTemplate bean) {
      OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(bean.getResource());
      restTemplate.setRequestFactory(bean.getRequestFactory());
      return restTemplate;
   }
   
   @Bean
   @LoadBalanced
   @Qualifier("oauth2JWTBalancedRestTemplate")
   public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2JWTBalancedRestTemplate(@Qualifier("oauth2JWTRestTemplate") OAuth2RestTemplate bean) {
      OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(bean.getResource());
      restTemplate.setRequestFactory(bean.getRequestFactory());
      return restTemplate;
   } 
}

@Service
public class ApiCall {

   @Value("${url}")
   private String uri;
   
   @Value("${endpoint}")
   private String endpoint;
   
   @Autowired
   @Qualifier("oauth2JWTBalancedRestTemplate")
   private OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate;

   public Response getTrdDetail(Request req) {
     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     HttpEntity<Request> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Request> (req, headers);
     return restTemplate.exchange(uri + endpoint, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Response.class);
   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure these dependencies

```
<groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
```

Configure the HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory bean and then inject it into your OAuth2RestTemplate bean:

```
@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setConnectTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds
        factory.setReadTimeout(5000);    // 5 seconds
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate() {
        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
        resourceDetails.setAccessTokenUri("YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_URI");
        resourceDetails.setClientId("YOUR_CLIENT_ID");
        resourceDetails.setClientSecret("YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET");
        resourceDetails.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.header);

        OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resourceDetails);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory());
        
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but we can not use token uri, client id and secret in our services. Because there is one general service for token accross organization and that service is bind with Oauth2RestTemplate.  @Qualifier("oauth2JWTBalancedRestTemplate")

Comment: Then just remove the token uri and client I'd part and use the service you required it's just the  httpcomponent is important.           public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory() {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
        factory.setConnectTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds
        factory.setReadTimeout(5000);    // 5 seconds
        return factory;
    }